# How to print the whole data even that which is below the scroll bar?

Tags: java, javafx

I have used the function `window.print()` which is taking only the data which is visible in the window for printing. I have tried using the overflow: visible also but that is also not helpful for me.

Comment: You can take a snapshot of the Node you want to print, and print the snapshot image. As far as I know it  makes an image of the whole Node by default (no matter the size or visibility).

Comment: Depends on the node you are trying to print. If it is a virtualized control (`TableView`, `ListView`, etc etc) then printing the node won't work, as layout is only performed for the part that is visible (cells aren't even created for the content scrolled out of view). If it's a normal control that doesn't use cells, then just printing the node itself should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some solutions in Google, maybe these will help:

https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-example-javafx-8

https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/introduction-by-example-javafx-8-printing/

For Node wise things maybe this question will also help: [JavaFX: printing a node across multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785651/javafx-printing-a-node-across-multiple-pages)